# Column Sorting doesn't ignore Capital letters

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections

I have the list as:

```java
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("James Smith");
al.add("MARIA GARCIA");
al.add("Maria Garcia");
al.add("DAVID SMITH");
```

I have used collection sort and ignoring capital letters.

```java
Collections.sort(al, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

It works for all of them but for `MARIA GARCIA` it still remains before the lower letters `Maria Garcia`. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` doesn't mean that Lower letter one comes first then Upper letter one or vice versa. You need to write a custom comparator for that.

Answer (score 5):

If two items are equal then they will not have their order changed*.

By using a comparator that ignores case, those strings are equal.

If you want to then apply a different sort when two items are equal, you can extend the comparator with `thenComparing` like so:

```
Collections.sort(al, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                           .thenComparing(
                               Comparator.comparing(String::toString)
                                         .reversed()));
```

Which can be written more simply in this case as:

```
Collections.sort(al, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                           .thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

*Which is why the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65217367/360211) works, but you do not want to sort multiple times, it's inefficient, harder for a reader to understand because it's written backwards, and is not a pattern you will be able to reuse in all other situations.

Comment: You might try `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder())` as with the natural order of `String` lower case letters come _after_ upper case letters.

Comment: Note that since Java 8, you can simply invoke `sort` on the `List` instance. Further, instead of `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER .thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder())` you can use the good old (if not to say ancient) `Collator.getInstance()`. So in short, `al.sort(Collator.getInstance());`

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210865/column-sorting-doesnt-ignore-capital-letters/65217367#comment115300855_65217367) for this most concise (IFAIK) solution.

The job can be done by simply passing [`Collator.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#getInstance()) to the `sort` method.

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(List.of("James Smith", "MARIA GARCIA", "Maria Garcia", "DAVID SMITH"));
        al.sort(Collator.getInstance());
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[DAVID SMITH, James Smith, Maria Garcia, MARIA GARCIA]
```

### Original answer

You can do it by sorting the list first in the reverse order and then the way you are already doing.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(List.of("James Smith", "MARIA GARCIA", "Maria Garcia", "DAVID SMITH"));
        Collections.sort(al, Comparator.reverseOrder());
        Collections.sort(al, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[DAVID SMITH, James Smith, Maria Garcia, MARIA GARCIA]
```

Comment: This particularly works because the sort is _stable_ as denoted in the [Java API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)): "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort"

Comment: Another lesser known gem: `al.sort(Collator.getInstance());` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *comparators chain* for this case as follows:

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("James Smith");
list.add("MARIA GARCIA");
list.add("Maria Garcia");
list.add("DAVID SMITH");

list.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
        .thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder()));

list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```yaml
DAVID SMITH
James Smith
Maria Garcia
MARIA GARCIA
```